# Move down one row all cells from one column (offset)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to move down one row all the cells from a column (in my case column C). It means if I have “X” written in cell C1, it should move down to Cell C2, if I have “Y” written in cell C1000,it should move down to Cell C1001…

I have the following error message:

> Run time error 1004, application defined or object defined error

```
Sub movedownrowcolumnC()    
    Range("C:C").Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: it's about time you unveil the secret and let us know what you actually wanted to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below macro.

```
Sub MoveDowncolumn()
Dim lastRow As Integer
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
lstrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
For i = lstrow To 1 Step -1
.Cells(i + 1, "C").Value = .Cells(i, "C").Value
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
```

although you most probably don't need to `Select` anything and just go with the `Range` variable:

```
Sub movedownrowcolumnC()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    myRange.Value = "myValue"
End Sub
```

While much more than just "good coding practice" is to always explicitly qualify a `Range` object up to its `Worksheet` reference:

```
Sub movedownrowcolumnC()
    Dim myRange As Range

    With Worksheets("mySheetName") ' reference wanted worksheet (change "mySheetName" to your actual relevantsheet name)
        Set myRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1) ' ser referenced worksheet column C cells right below last not empty one
    End With

    myRange.Value = "myValue"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you ask for this?

```
Range("C1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: thanks a lot all for your reply... I tested them all, the solution which works the best for me was the one of Nandu...

Answer (score 1):

You can you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .Range("C1").Value = "Test" Then
           .Rows(.Range("C1").Row + 1).Select
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess this answer doesn't address OP's question. Beware of masked brave down voters!

Comment: @DisplayName thanks for your comment, but as far as i have understand OP wants to test if a cell contains a value and if so to move one row down and select the whole row.Right?

Comment: I would say no, but I admit her question is not crystal clear

Comment: so, in  these case i should delete the answer to avoid confusion?

Comment: Actually, we all need a more clear description from @Xavi about his actual need.

Comment: thanks a lot all for your reply... I tested them all, the solution which works the best for me was the one of Nandu...